# How can I use dropbox core API in php

Tags: php, dropbox

I am trying to use Dropbox core API in php (https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php) but I am stuck while running following code solution given on stack overflow

```
  <?php

require_once "dropbox-php-sdk-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/autoload.php";

use \Dropbox as dbx;

$dropbox_config = array(
    'key'    => 'your_key',
    'secret' => 'your_secret'
);

$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJson($dropbox_config);
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");

$authorizeUrl = $webAuth->start();
echo "1. Go to: " . $authorizeUrl . "<br>";
echo "2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first).<br>";
echo "3. Copy the authorization code and insert it into $authCode.<br>";

$authCode = trim('DjsR-iGv4PAAAAAAAAAAAbn9snrWyk9Sqrr2vsdAOm0');

list($accessToken, $dropboxUserId) = $webAuth->finish($authCode);
echo "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "<br>";

$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");

// Uploading the file
$f = fopen("working-draft.txt", "rb");
$result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/working-draft.txt", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
fclose($f);
print_r($result);

// Get file info
$file = $dbxClient->getMetadata('/working-draft.txt');

// sending the direct link:
$dropboxPath = $file['path'];
$pathError = dbx\Path::findError($dropboxPath);
if ($pathError !== null) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "Invalid <dropbox-path>: $pathError\n");
    die;
}

// The $link is an array!
$link = $dbxClient->createTemporaryDirectLink($dropboxPath);
// adding ?dl=1 to the link will force the file to be downloaded by the client.
$dw_link = $link[0]."?dl=1";

echo "Download link: ".$dw_link."<br>";

?>
```

When I Run this code I got this error

[image]

I am commenting some code from dropbox core API which is in 
dropbox-php-sdk-1.1.6/lib/Dropbox/RequestUtil.php to run dropbox core API in 5.6 php version

```
if (strlen((string) PHP_INT_MAX) < 19) {
    // Looks like we're running on a 32-bit build of PHP.  This could cause problems because some of the numbers
    // we use (file sizes, quota, etc) can be larger than 32-bit ints can handle.
    throw new \Exception("The Dropbox SDK uses 64-bit integers, but it looks like we're running on a version of PHP that doesn't support 64-bit integers (PHP_INT_MAX=" . ((string) PHP_INT_MAX) . ").  Library: \"" . __FILE__ . "\"");
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You're using version 1 of the Dropbox API which has been retired. https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/06/updated-api-v1-deprecation-timeline/

Answer (score 4):

Dropbox v1 API [has been shutdown](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/) on September 28, 2017. The library you are trying to use is made for this retired v1.

You should use one of the [v2 PHP libraries](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/) instead:

- [dropbox-php-sdk](https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk) by Kunal Varma
- [dropbox-v2-php](https://github.com/Alorel/dropbox-v2-php) by Alorel

Answer (score 0):

FYI, API v1 is being retired, so it will return a 400 error with this message: {“error”: “v1_retired”}. This means your work/code relying on API v1 endpoints may stop working.

I think you have not migrated to v2, check out the migration guide for more details.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/migration-guide